# How can a spark Label be skinned?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I would like to add some fancy drawing beyond the CSS formatting.
How can I put a skin on a spark Label ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, +1 for a good question.  The approach I would take would be to custom component that wraps a Label with a SkinnableComponent, which then allows you to specify a skin class since the Label component itself is not skinnable.  I would then take a look at the Button and ButtonSkin classes to mimic passing the label text into the Label component in your skin.  Hope that helps.

Comment: yeah... the closest I got was skinning a TextInput,(editable=false, selectable=false). it in turn contains a RichText component to render the text.
I just thought there should be an easier way.
thanks